# JSLint "bad escapement" on a multiply sign

Tags: javascript, jslint

I need to display a multiply sign (×) in a modal being created by JavaScript like so:

```
$(blah).dialog({ something: '\327' });
```

However, JSLint says this is a "bad escapement". Unfortunately, using an HTML entity like `&times` doesn't work in this situation—only the escape code will display properly. Anyone know why this is a bad escapement and if there's a way around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. JSLint complains: “Don't use octal: '\3'. Use '\u....' instead”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the hexadecimal escape: `'\u00D7'`.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea as to why the octal is bad?

Comment: The digits part of an octal literal starts with a zero.  So what you wanted was `\0327`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `×` if your file encoding is all right.